# Using base template static member by derived template static member in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, static, initialization

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> struct A
{
    T x;
    A(T X) : x(X) { }   
    static const A a;
};
template <typename T> const A<T> A<T>::a(5);

template <typename T> struct B : public A<T>
{
    B(T X) : A<T>(X) { }
    static const B b;
};
template <typename T> const B<T> B<T>::b(A<T>::a.x);

int main()
{
    //auto test0 = A<int>::a.x;
    auto test1 = B<int>::a.x;
    auto test2 = B<int>::b.x;
    auto test3 = A<int>::a.x;
    std::cout << "test1 = " << test1 << "\ttest2 = " << test2 <<
        "\ttest3 = " << test3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Running this code](https://ideone.com/Y0nHkw) may give the following text:

```
test1 = 5    test2 = 5    test3 = 5
```

But not when running on any Visual Studio up to 2015. VS produces:

```
test1 = 5    test2 = 0    test3 = 5
```

unless you uncomment definition of test0 variable in main(). Why?

Looks like MSVC++ doesn't initialize base template struct static member, unless you explicitly instantiate it before using derived struct. This is probably related to dynamic constant initialization, but I'm not sure what's really happening here.

How to overcome this behavior? I need `B<int>::b.x` to be equal to `B<int>::a.x` everytime, without forcing myself to remember to instantiate `A<int>` first.
Hackish trickeries are acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way to overcome this behavior is to upgrade your compiler.